# OpenCms Element (may be page) properties

Tags: opencms

I am working with OpenCms 8, I having a problem I am suppose to define custom properties to page and external links, but when we define new properties one can add any input, I want to limit that input, i.e. Yes/No, is it possible any suggestions?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With custom properties, do you mean 'properties' as the one you define when clicking on the page's icon and the selecting 'properties', or do you mean custom fields (let's call it attributes) in the schema xsd for your specific page type? Because that's a difference.
For properties, you can't validate the user's input, for attributes (which you can also map to properties on the other hand), you can restrict the user's input, i.e. by still keeping the type to 'string', however, only providing a selection list with 'yes'/'no' as the options.

To answer your question more precisely, please let me know which schema/xsd you're using for your page.
Are you new to OpenCms, or have you used it before? Just to understand your experience level with it.

Comment: I am new to opencms, using default schemas pre-created in samples, and yes I am referring to right click-> properties -> and then Define, also please if you can tell how to create a selection list with 'yes'/'no' as the options. Thank You

Comment: Which one of the pre-defined schemas exactly are you using? To carve an example based on that.

Comment: I am creating a container page and then  right click at the page and select properties and then advanced where I can define new properties, that's where I want to add my property (may be a drop down list) thank you